# How to change the MySQL fields name before printing in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting random fields values from a MySQL database. The fields are selected dynamically and these are different on each query. Now I want to assign the description to every field  and print the field description.

For example I have selected two fields such as: `web_seo` and `web_maintenance` then I want to show the above fields as (Do you want your website SEO) and (Do you want your website maintenance from our company) respectively.

Comment: Please post what have u tried?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Where is the **Code**??? So we can help you..

Comment: You can for example assign each possible key to an array of names.

Comment: @Voitcus i'm agree with you

Answer (score 1):

if its `MySql` you can assign comments to the actual column within the database.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CHANGE COLUMN col col INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'This is the new comment';
```

You can then select these comments using the `information_schema` (MySql 5.0+)

```
SELECT 
  comments FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE 
  table_schema = 'dbname' 
AND 
  table_name = 'tbl'
```

**Edit**

Forgot to say, the `information_schema` contains all the metadata for all your databases, it may be worth creating a new `MySQL` user that has specific access to the schema/tables required to avoid the obvious security issues.

More information can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Comment: Thanks, is what i meant with _to this schema_ but will edit to make clearer